# Oauth 1.0 signature

Tags: php, oauth, php-curl

I am having an issue generating an oauth 1.0 signature could anyone see what's wrong?

the api response is : "Invalid Request: Missing signature"

to use the code launch script from commande line with consumer_id as first argument and consumer_secret as second argument.

"php 'script_name' 'consumer_id' 'consumer_secret'"

and dont forget to change base_url in code if you want to test on other api

here is my code:

```
<?php


function print_help(){
    echo "usage: <script> <consumer_id> <consumer_secret>";
}

if ($argc != 3) {
    print_help();
    exit;
}
$base_url = "https://sso.openx.com/api/index/initiate";
$time = (string)time();
$signature_method= "HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_version = "1.0";
$nonce = "ZNWVga";
$realm = "";
$consumer_key  = (string)$argv[1];
$consumer_secret  = (string)$argv[2];
$base_string  = "POST&" . rawurlencode($base_url) ."&".
rawurlencode('realm="' . $realm .
'"&oauth_nonce="' . $nonce .
'"&oauth_timestamp="' . $time. 
'"&oauth_consumer_key="' . $consumer_key . 
'"&oauth_signature_method="' . $signature_method. 
'"&oauth_version="' . $oauth_version.
'"&oauth_callback="oob"');


$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",     rawurlencode($consumer_secret . "&"), $base_string, true ));


$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: identity';
$headers[] = 'Connection: close';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: 0';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="'.$realm.
'", oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.
'", oauth_timestamp="' . $time .
'", oauth_consumer_key="' . $consumer_key .
'", oauth_signature_method="' . $signature_method . 
'", oauth_version="'.$oauth_version.
'", oauth_signature="' . (string)$signature .
'",oauth_callback="oob"';



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,        true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$head = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
print_r($head);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($data);



//echo "\n\n\n\n output -> " + $out
?>
```

Thank you all in advance.

Happy Coding !

Comment: hash_hmac($algo, $data, $key) - you swapped $data and $key. did you resolved the issue? i have nearly the same problem, now: Invalid Request: Wrong Signature

Comment: I also have the same error as "Invalid Request: Missing signature". Did you tried to form the oauth_signature manually and succeeded in getting the token instead of php code?